# Terraform - ERROR: Function Calls Not allowed

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

In my terraform main.tf file I have the content

```
`
provider "google" {
    credentials = file("terraform-371117-9d27713c1607.json")

    project = "terraform-371117"
    region = "asia-south1"
    zone = "asia-south1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "VPC" {
    name = "practice-network"
    auto_create_subnetworks = true
  
}
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "tf-state-devv"
    prefix = "Terraform/State"
    credentials = file("terraform-371117-9d27713c1607.json")
  }
}
`
```

When I'm trying to run terraform init command to initialize I am getting the following error

```
`terraform init

Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Function calls not allowed
│
│   on main.tf line 18, in terraform:
│   18:     credentials = file("terraform-371117-9d27713c1607.json")
│
│ Functions may not be called here.`
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the `file` function and pass the path directly:

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "tf-state-devv"
    prefix = "Terraform/State"
    credentials = "terraform-371117-9d27713c1607.json"
  }
}
```